# How to fix the unknown Configuration org.animb.valuation.valBase in my Rodin Platform Event-B project?

Tags: modeling, formal-methods, event-b

I have import a fully Refined model in my latest version of Rodin Platform and I am trying to use a IUMLB with ProB animator in this project. But since the project already had a preconfigured AnimB animator which the latest Rodin Software does not support. The error states "unknown configuration org.animb.valuation.valBase".

How to remove or fix this AnimB configuration from the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to Fix this problem myself :).

Not all that I had But this specific problem was fixed by opening the file in Text Editor where the error was showing in and I just deleted the org.animb.valuation.valBase from the eventb.core.configuration as shown below:

Earlier:

`<org.eventb.core.contextFile org.eventb.core.configuration="org.eventb.core.fwd;org.animb.valuation.valBase;de.prob.symbolic.ctxBase;de.prob.units.mchBase" version="3">`

Later:

`<org.eventb.core.contextFile org.eventb.core.configuration="org.eventb.core.fwd;de.prob.symbolic.ctxBase;de.prob.units.mchBase" version="3">`

This fixed my problem. No more errors :)